# Add a space next to an echo in a loop - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add space next to an echo of categories assigned to a post:

```
<?php  
   $category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID); 
   foreach($category_detail as $cd)
   { 
     echo $cd->slug; 
   }
?>
```

The above code prints all categories assigned to a post, but it prints it like this:

```
category1category5
```

how can I add a space between each category printed? ie  category1 category5

Answer (score 3):

with some magic:

```
echo $cd->slug.' ';
```

Comment: this one will do but this one will leave a trailing space :-)

Comment: an invisible  trailing space, oh the horror

Comment: @Dagon never mind, but from my experience I won't like to leave a single space anywhere visible/invisible no matter what it is :) Thanks

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet. its all good, i would probably be the same, but for html its trivial to leave it in

Answer (score 0):

What is the logic behind the code is: we will test that if this is the first id to print or not. If this is the first id to print then we won't do anything. But if it's not the first id then we will print a space before printing it. That way every id will be separated by a single space and there will be no leading or trailing spaces.

Code:

```
<?php  
  $category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID); 
  $i = 0;
  foreach($category_detail as $cd)
  { 
   if($i)echo " ";
   echo $cd->slug;
   $i=1;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$count = 0;
foreach($category_detail as $cd)
{
   //if first item, don't append space, else append space
   echo ($count == 0 ? $cd->slug : ' '.$cd->slug);
   $count++;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something simple like this:

```
<?php  
   $category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID); 
   $sep='';
   foreach($category_detail as $cd)
   { 
     echo "${sep}".$cd->slug;
     $sep=' '; 
   }
?>
```

No trailing or leading space.

Comment: Oh, and you may want to use ... $sep='&nbsp;'; ... for displaying non-breaking space in HTML etc.

Comment: creating the var seems like overfill

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version using implode:

```
$category_detail = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category_slug_collect = array_map(
                             function($obj) { return $obj->slug; }, 
                             $category_detail
                         );
echo implode($category_slug_collect, ' ');
```